# Add Active Toggle Class to Parent Div When Clicking on Child Button

Tags: javascript

How do I add a "active" toggle class to parent div when clicking on child button in Javascript. I can do this in jQuery but I wanted to use pure Javascript.

Here is the sample html snippets for better understanding.

```
<div class="parent-div">
      <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
      <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
      <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
      <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
      <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
    </div>
```

I dont want to use `document.getElementById('')` because there will be sevaral sections and in each section will be contaning the button to add toggle class.

I tried some other examples, but they are based on ID and not class, I can't repeat the same id and it's not working too.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest allows you to find a parent matching a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'closest' to get the element that is closest to that element with a specific selector. In this case the selector is class.

We can also check if the class is already set and turn it off again, thus making a toggle.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-class-button");

var setActive = function() {
  let closestElement = this.closest('.parent-div');

  if (closestElement.classList.contains('active')) {
    closestElement.classList.remove('active')
  } else {
    closestElement.classList.add('active')
  }
};

Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', setActive);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
  <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
</div>

<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
  <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
</div>

<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
  <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
</div>

<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="title-of-the-section">Section title</div>
  <button class="toggle-class-button">Add "active" class to parent div of ['parent-div']</button>
</div>
```